# Get data between 20:00 and 05:00 in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that contains some data along with a `datetime` column.

I want to fetch data between 20:00 and 05:00 clock.

I have following query but could not get succedeed

```
select 
    txt_target_cell_id, count(*) as 'Total Count', txt_longitude, txt_latitude
from 
    tbl_cdr_analyzer_load
where 
    DATEPART(hour, dat_start) between 20 and 05
group by 
    txt_target_cell_id, txt_longitude, txt_latitude
```

Comment: Do you want the data from *all* dates from 20:00 to 24:00 and 00:00 to 04:00 or the data from *one specific* day from 20:00 to 24:00 and *the next day* from 00:00 to 04:00?

Comment: Okay, then Stasels answer should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Your `BETWEEN` statement means:

```
DATEPART(hour, dat_start) >= 20 AND DATEPART(hour, dat_start)<=04
```

Which is always false.

You can try to do it like this:

```
select 
    txt_target_cell_id,count(*) as 'Total Count',txt_longitude,txt_latitude
from 
    tbl_cdr_analyzer_load
where 
    DATEPART(hour, dat_start) <= 04 OR DATEPART(hour, dat_start)>=20
group by 
    txt_target_cell_id,txt_longitude,txt_latitude
```

Comment: Don't you think there must be 'AND' opertor use instead of 'OR'

Comment: No, because if its `AND` then the query will be between 04 to 20 as you tried before

Comment: this will not work where `DATEPART(hour, dat_start) <= 20 OR DATEPART(hour, dat_start)>=23`. Here data between 0 to 23 hrs will comes out

Comment: @RajeevKumar My solution will show all hours between `0 to 4` AND  between `20 to 23`. This is what was requested in the question. I can't understand your new problem but I will be happy to help you out

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    txt_target_cell_id, count(*) as 'Total Count', txt_longitude, txt_latitude
from 
    tbl_cdr_analyzer_load
where 
    DATEPART(hour, dat_start) between 04 and 20 //Change here
group by 
    txt_target_cell_id, txt_longitude, txt_latitude
```

It because the id  Between valu1 and value2 is equivalent to.
where id>=value1 and id<=values2
to get desire result,,,,

```
Select 
    txt_target_cell_id,count(*) as 'Total Count',txt_longitude,txt_latitude
from 
    tbl_cdr_analyzer_load
where 
    DATEPART(hour, dat_start) <= 04 OR DATEPART(hour, dat_start)>=20
group by 
    txt_target_cell_id,txt_longitude,txt_latitude
```

Comment: If i put beween 4 and 20 does it not give me result between 4'o clock morning till 8'o clock night. i wanna between 8'o Clock night till 4'o clock morning..

Comment: I think he meant the opposite: dates between 20 to 04 the next day (i.e night activity)

Comment: i told you about between, and why you are not getting resuklt to get result use @Stasel query